# Selenium, does it support multiple input values

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does Selenium support passing a range of input values?

I did some Selenium training a few years ago and seem to recall there was a feature that allowed you to pass a table of values to a testcase. I can't recall the details, and can't find any reference to it in the docs? I could have been dreaming! My general recollection was that you could pass something like;

```
FirstName | Lastname
Bob       | Smith
Andy      | Franks
```

And somehow make this data the subject of the test.

Comment: Passing this to what? How `exactly` are you planning to run these tests?

Comment: you can get data from excel and pass to field on website.

Comment: The question isn't to explanatory! What exactly is the problem you are asking about? Please edit the post to include more specific query

Comment: You can either pass your values from a file (probably excel) or use TestNG wit DataProvider to pass a 2d object array. Now it all depends on how you are storing these values. Edit your question and add this detail.

Comment: Or you can start from a table or view in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you show in your question I'm thinking what you are remembering is something like:

```
Scenario: fooing the bar
  Given some data
  When the user foos the bar
  Then the bar shows
    | FirstName | Lastname |
    | Bob       | Smith    |
    | Andy      | Franks   |
```

That's the [Gherkin language](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin). Test runners that understand Gherkin exist for most general purpose languages. The table in the last step is something that the test runner will pass to the implementation of the step. You have to write the implementation of the step yourself and are responsible for passing the data to Selenium in a format that Selenium understands. How you do this depends on the specific test you are trying to perform with Selenium.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have played with Gherkin before too. I'm sure that's where my confusion came from!